# Add column to dataframe base on regular expression (Python)

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to add a new column to a dataframe that comes from regular expression used on text from first column? How this could be done?

```
  re.compile ('\S+@\S+', s)
```

And I would like to use that regexp on each row for each text from frst column and ass another column add the outcome of regexp.

Comment: so you meant to fetch the column names from the first columns in first raw ?

Comment: In my first column I have strings. I want to add in my second column for each row  the outcome of regexp used on each record (string)

Answer (score 0):

```
for idx, data_string in df.itertuples(name='first_column'):

    # do things with the data_string here

    # save result in second column
    df.loc[idx, 'second_column'] = result
```

Maybe I get you wrong, but isn't it just iterating over all rows and save the result from your regexp in the second column?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas DataFrame all must be same length ,so the row which match regex is the only row going to be in dataframe at the end.

You just need to define function which apply regex on string
and use apply function in pandas series and insert it to dataframe at the end.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['123','12','b23','134'],'col_2':['a','b','c','d']})

df
```

```
Out[1]: 
  col_1 col_2
0   123     a
1    12     b
2   b23     c
3   134     d
```

```
def regex(string):
    pattern = re.compile(r"\d{1,2}")
    result = pattern.match(string)
    if result:
        return  result.group()
    return np.nan #Here if not match so i can drop all row later

new_col = df.col_1.apply(regex)

df.insert(loc =2,column='new_col',value=new_col)

df = df.dropna()
df
```

```
Out[2]: 
  col_1 col_2 new_col
0   123     a      12
1    12     b      12
3   134     d      13
```

Comment: I can't remove rows that doesn't match regex. Can we set null there or '' ? Do we just return null in regex func?

Comment: No You remove it if you want or leave it ,it's up to you. if you would like to leave it just not use df.dropna() which remove null values